# Two-way binding for textfield without Em.Textfield

Tags: ember.js

i trying to make this

```
<input type="text" {{bindAttr value="controller.term"}}>
```

but dont work properly, the changes only work from controller. i'm force to use the following

```
{{view Em.TextField valueBinding="controller.term"}}
```

there is one way to make this without using the previous snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Why not extend Ember.TextField to do what you want?

Let me know exactly what you're trying to do, and I'll bet we can find a solution this way. I'll edit my answer when I know more sepcifics, but for now:

### Extending Ember.TextField

Let's say you want to put a maxlength and a placeholder on the input.

```js
App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  maxlength: 20,
  placeholder: 'Some placeholder text',
  attributeBindings: ['maxlength', 'placeholder']
});
```

Then you could put this in your template:

```
{{view App.MyTextField valueBinding="controller.term"}}
```

Comment: If you still need help I'm happy to see if I can solve your specific problem this way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious - why do you not want to use Ember.TextField?

The template with `{{bindAttr value="controller.term"}}` will not propagate changes from the view to the controller, since the view has no idea that its value has been changed. You've got to handle `change`, `keyUp`, `focusOut` events yourself and update data accordingly. Guess what - all this you get for free when using Ember.TextField.

If you still want to go the first way, have a look at Ember.TextSupport - this mixin enables data flow from the view to the controller.

Comment: i read all documentation and the Ember.TextField source code it does exactly that. thanks for your response